# Show that $ 2^{ab}+1=(2^{a}+1)(2^{ab-b}-2^{ab-2b}+2^{ab-3b}+...+1) $ where b is an odd number and( a, b) are natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, elementary-functions

Show that  :

$$ 2^{ab}+1=(2^{a}+1)(2^{ab-b}-2^{ab-2b}+2^{ab-3b}+...+1) $$

where b is an odd number and( a, b) are natrual numbers.

So far I’ve tried to use a similar identity as that used to prove the power of a mearsenne prime is a prime but I can’t figure out a way to express this$ -1^k $product infront of the polynomial series. Any hints?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I am pretty certain that you mean $$\left(2^{ab-a}-2^{ab-2a}+2^{ab-3a}-\cdots+1\right)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just expand the right-hand side, and see that almost every term in
$$
2^a\left(2^{ab-a}-2^{ab-2a}+2^{ab-3a}-\cdots+1\right)
$$
cancels against a corresponding term from
$$
1\left(2^{ab-a}-2^{ab-2a}+2^{ab-3a}-\cdots+1\right)
$$